# postgresql find the average time between 2 or more date

Tags: postgresql-9.2

i have a table tbltrans

```
transno | agent name | date|

--------+-----------+-------

 1 01   | waw   |2014-10-10|

 1 02   | waw   |2014-10-15|

 1 03   | waw   |2014-10-20|

 1 04   | waw   |2014-10-30|
```

i want a query for postgresql that calculate the average time for agentname

the result is like this:

```
agent name | average time|

--------+------------

 waw      | 5days      |
```

i hope somebody help me. .
thanks and more power :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select agent_name, 
       (max(date) - min(date)) / count(*) as average_days
from tbltrans
group by agent_name;
```

Comment: no sir. .it must be. . find the difference between those date and find the average between the difference . . 5+5+10=20 then 20/3 so the average time is 6.66 . . sorry for the result in my post.

Comment: @MichaelDelgadoBeray Hmm, the `20` is calculated this way. Wouldn't `count(*)-1` then accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: B-)

```
with diff(agent_name, values) as 
(
 select agent_name, date - lag(date,1,date) over (partition by agent_name order by date) from agents
)
select agent_name, 
       case when count(values) = 1 then '0 days'
            else to_char(sum(values)::float / (count(values) - 1), '999.99') || ' days'
       end
from diff
group by agent_name;
```

I used [Windowing functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html) and [Common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) in the solution